# How to require all files within a directory using webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I am on webpack v4.

A number of libraries commonly ask a URL to some configuration or data file (that's part of the application's sources) to be provided at some API call. This is easily doable in webpack by `require`-ing the file in question (and having a `file-loader` configured).

I am now faced with a slightly different problem: a certain API requires the relative URL to some directory where a bunch of files will be found. What is the proper way to handle this in webpack? As far as I can tell, it is not possible to `require` an entire directory and there's no "directory-loader".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform the require calls at compile-time, you can use `require.context`:

> This can be useful if you want to require all files in a directory or matching a pattern.

Read the webpack docs for more information [1].

Example from the docs:

```
function importAll (r) {
  r.keys().forEach(r);
}

importAll(require.context('../components/', true, /\.js$/));
```

[1] https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext